# What format should ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth use?

Tags: wif

I can't find it specified anywhere. I *did* find a Microsoft example that had "5/5/1955". Is that d/m/y or y/m/d.

I'm guessing that I probably ought to use ISO 8601, but it would be nice to know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [OASIS spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/imi/identity/v1.0/os/identity-1.0-spec-os.pdf), the type associated with URI
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/dateofbirth is `xs:date`, so it should be a normal XML date format... which is indeed ISO-8601, according to [XML Schema Part 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#date). (That talks about the time zone for a date being representable, which strikes me as a little odd, but never mind.)